# What '\v' and '@<=' in '/\v(A)@<=b+\1' regex means?

Tags: regular-expression

The expression:

```
/\v(A)@<=b+\1
```

What

```
\v
```

and

```
@<=
```

means?

It's sure this is able to find 'bbbA' in "AbbbA'-s.
It's trivial that the number n of b-s can be any n > 1.

Comment: Check out the help [`:help /\v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv)
and [`:help /\@!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%21)

Comment: Ohh, didn't know help is so smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [`:help /\v`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5Cv):

> Use of "\v" means that in the pattern after it all ASCII characters except '0'-'9', 'a'-'z', 'A'-'Z' and '_' have a special meaning.

`\v` is also called "very magic" mode. By adding `\v` one may often type regexes with a smaller amount of characters, since one does not need to escape things. As an example, `\v(a|b|c)` is equivalent to `\(a\|b\|c\)`.

From [`:help /\@<=`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D):

> Matches with zero width if the preceding atom matches just before what follows.

This can often (but not always) be replaced with `\zs`, which is both faster and easier to type. An example, using `\v` to reduce the escaping: `\v(foo)@<=bar` will match any `bar` in `foobar`. This is equivalent to `foo\zsbar`.

---

The regex `/\v(A)@<=b+\1` will match any number of `b`s followed by an `A` as long as it is preceded by an `A`, e.g. `A[bA]` and `A[bbbbbba]`, where `[]` denotes the beginning and end of the matched pattern. This specific regex is much better to write as `A\zsb\+A`, which will be both faster and is easier to type.